How to install OpenMP for clang on windows
I'm using the clang compiler from winlibs on windows [GCC 14.1.0 (with POSIX threads) + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 18.1.8 + MinGW-w64 12.0.0 (UCRT) - release 3]. I've noticed that it only includes OpenMP support for GCC, but not for Clang. How can I install OpenMP for Clang on Windows?

Works for me on msys2 clang: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075
